# Why does `setup.py develop` not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, distutils, setup.py

I would like to install my Python module in development mode. As I have seen in many examples `python setup.py develop` is supposed to do that. But the `develop` command does not exist for my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import os

src = ["_NetworKit.pyx"]    # list of source files
modules = [Extension("_NetworKit",
                    src,
                    language = "c++",
                    extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp", "-std=c++11", "-O3", "-DNOGTEST"],
                    extra_link_args=["-fopenmp", "-std=c++11"],
                    libraries=["NetworKit-Core-O"],
                    library_dirs=["../"])]

for e in modules:
    e.cython_directives = {"embedsignature" : True}

setup(name="_NetworKit",
     cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
     ext_modules=modules,
     py_modules = ["NetworKit.py"])
```

(Note the Cython extension module).

What am I missing? Do I need to modify the `setup.py`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `develop` command is a part of [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode). Install setuptools and replace the first line in `setup.py` with this:

```
from setuptools import setup
```