# Structuring python projects without path hacks

Tags: python, python-import, directory-structure, organization, project-structure

I have a shared python library that I use in multiple projects, so the structure looks like this:

```
Project1
    main.py <--- (One of the projects that uses the library)
...
sharedlib
    __init__.py
    ps_lib.py
    another.py
```

Now in each project's *main.py* I use the following hack to make it work:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

import sharedlib.ps_lib
...
```

Is there a way to do it without using this hack? Or is there a better way to organize the projects structure?

Comment: Why not just "install" the `sharedlib` as package? Then you can import it everywhere.

Comment: @Rahul I don't like this approach because it's not elegant, and in every module in the project you would have "from .. import ..."

Comment: @MSeifert but then after each small fix in the shared library, I would have to pip install it again

Comment: Not necessarily, you can install a "symlink" with something like `python setup.py develop`. That way if you change `sharedlib` the changes will take effect immediatly (or after an interpreter restart if you're using an interactive interpreter).

Comment: @MSeifert That's a good idea! Will the symlink work in windows?

Comment: I never had problems with `python setup.py develop` and I'm using windows. However that requires you to make the `sharedlib` package installable (I always used `setuptools.setup` but it probably also works with `distutils.setup`). :)

Comment: @MSeifert Ok so maybe this is the correct approach, you can post your answer

Comment: @Drxxd You don't need to install after every edit if you run `pip install -e ..`

Comment: @MSeifert I believe the `develop` command is only available in `setuptools`, but not in `distutils`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 You're right. I just found ["Why does `setup.py develop` not work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996639/why-does-setup-py-develop-not-work) when using pure `distutils`...

Comment: this only works if the script is run from the same directory as what it's in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way would be to make `sharedlib` a real package. That means changing the structure a bit:

```
sharedlib/
    sharedlib/
        __init__.py
        ps_lib.py
        another.py
    setup.py
```

And using something like this in the `setup.py` (taken partially from [Python-packaging "Minimal Structure"](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='sharedlib',
      version='0.1',
      description='...',
      license='...',
      packages=['sharedlib'],   # you might need to change this if you have subfolders.
      zip_safe=False)
```

Then install it with [`python setup.py develop`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode) or [`pip install -e .`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-e) when in the root folder of the `sharedlib` package.

That way (using the `develop` or `-e` option) changes to the contents of `sharedlib/sharedlib/*` files will be visible without re-installing the `sharedlib` package - although you may need to restart the interpreter if you're working in an interactive interpreter. That's because the interpreter caches already imported packages.

From the `setuptools` documentation:

> Setuptools allows you to deploy your projects for use in a common directory or staging area, but without copying any files. **Thus, you can edit each project’s code in its checkout directory, and only need to run build commands when you change a project’s C extensions or similarly compiled files**. [...]
>
> To do this, use the `setup.py develop` command.

(emphasis mine)

The most important thing is that you can `import sharedlib` everywhere now - no need to insert the `sharedlib` package in the `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` anymore because Python (or at least the Python where you installed it) now treats `sharedlib` like any other installed package.

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is to use bash entry-scripts for the python scripts. Our directory structure would look similar to the following:

```
/opt/stackoverflow/
                 -> bin
                 -> conf
                 -> lib
                 -> log
```

Our lib folder then contains all of our sub-projects

```
/opt/stackoverflow/lib/
                    -> python_algorithms
                    -> python_data_structures
                    -> python_shared_libraries
```

and then when we want to execute a python script, we'll execute it via a bash script within the bin directory

```
/opt/stackoverflow/bin/
                    -> quick_sort.sh
                    -> merge_sort.sh
```

and if we cat one of our entry scripts

```
cat merge_sort.sh

#!/bin/bash
export STACKOVERFLOW_HOME=/opt/stackoverflow
export STACKOVERFLOW_BIN=${STACKOVERFLOW_HOME}/bin
export STACKOVERFLOW_LIB=${STACKOVERFLOW_HOME}/lib
export STACKOVERFLOW_LOG=${STACKOVERFLOW_HOME}/log
export STACKOVERFLOW_CONF=${STACKOVERFLOW_HOME}/conf

# Do any pre-script server work here

export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${STACKOVERFLOW_LIB}

/usr/bin/python "${STACKOVERFLOW_LIB}/python_algorithms/merge_sort.py" $* 2>&1
```

Comment: doesn't this cause your `PYTHONPATH` to grow? every time you run this bash script, the path `${STACKOVERFLOW_LIB}` is appended (regardless if it is part of the path already).

Comment: Assuming you use the 1 user for everything and dont log out of the server it will continue to grow.