# Install from git and step rpy2

Tags: git

I try to install

[this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD)

git locally:

However when I execute the command in bash 
python create_text_folder.py -i Apache -o output_dir
I receive this error:

```
MINGW64 /C/git/Personality-Recognition-in-SD (master)
$ python create_text_folder.py -i Apache -o output_dir
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_text_folder.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MailCorpus as mc
  File "C:\git\Personality-Recognition-in-SD\MailCorpus.py", line 1, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpy2'
```

I run it as admin. How can I procide to fix it?

Comment: Note to moderators: this is 100% on-topic, and has nothing to do with "general computing hardware and software".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Git bash session from  a [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), you need to double-check your [Python installation and PYTHONPATH, as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46812191/6309).

The other approach would be to repeat the clone+installation steps of [`collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD`](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD#installation), but in a WSL session (a [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)), which might be more compatible with that program.